# Why might my .click event not fire?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a carousel using jQuery. I have a prev class and a next class. A button and an a tag, respectively. Neither .click event works. The events are inside document.ready.

```
<button type="button" class="prev">&#10094;</button>
<a class="next">&#10095;</a>
```

.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#slide1").show();

    $(".next").click(function () {
        if ($slideNumber < 2){
            switch ($slideNumber){
                case 0: $("#slide0").hide();
                case 1: $("#slide1").hide();
            }
            $slideNumber++
        }else { ...
    });

    $(".prev").click(function () {
        if ($slideNumber > 0){
            switch ($slideNumber){
                case 1: $("#slide1").hide();
                case 2: $("#slide2").hide();
            }
            $slideNumber--
        }else { ...
```

Comment: Are you sure it's the click events failing, or the logic within them? Have you checked the console to see if there's any errors?

Comment: When you click them, do you see any errors in browser's console?

Comment: I believe, it might be failing inside your `switch/case`

Comment: your switch cases missing a `break` statement or it won't work as you seem to expect it

Comment: there are no errors in the browsers console. I added a break point at the start of the if statements and it never gets there, but yes, I should add breaks to the switch

Comment: I've answered this question myself, I have to wait 2 days to mark it as answered, but the issue was because of html elements overlapping; I was never clicking the actual button because it was covered by another element

Answer (score 0):

> use $(ducument).on() instead of..

**$(".prev").click(function ()** and  **$(".next").click(function ()**

```
$(ducument).on(".next","click",function () {
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because of overlap of HTML elements. This caused the clickable area of the button/a tag to be obstructed.